# How do I convert svg code to svg path image?

Tags: svg

How would I be able to convert this type of svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <metadata><?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c145 79.163499, 2018/08/13-16:40:22        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/"
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
            xmlns:xmpRights="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/">
        <xmpRights:Marked>True</xmpRights:Marked>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>

<?xpacket end="w"?></metadata>
 <image id="N_side_slit" data-name="N side slit" x="21" y="44" width="178" height="148" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

To a type of svg that has a path and is usable in html like this:

```
<svg width="36px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 36 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <path d="M8.98885921,23.8523026 C8.8942483,23.9435442 8.76801031,24 8.62933774,24 L2.03198365,24 C1.73814918,24 1.5,23.7482301 1.5,23.4380086 C1.5,23.2831829 1.55946972,23.1428989 1.65570253,23.0416777 L13.2166154,12.4291351 C13.3325814,12.3262031 13.4061076,12.1719477 13.4061076,11.999444 C13.4061076,11.8363496 13.3401502,11.6897927 13.2352673,11.587431 L1.68841087,0.990000249 C1.57298556,0.88706828 1.5,0.733668282 1.5,0.561734827 C1.5,0.251798399 1.73814918,2.85130108e-05 2.03198365,2.85130108e-05 L8.62933774,2.85130108e-05 C8.76855094,2.85130108e-05 8.89532956,0.0561991444 8.98994048,0.148296169 L21.4358709,11.5757407 C21.548593,11.6783875 21.6196864,11.8297916 21.6196864,11.999444 C21.6196864,12.1693815 21.5483227,12.3219261 21.4350599,12.4251432 L8.98885921,23.8523026 Z M26.5774333,23.8384453 L20.1765996,17.9616286 C20.060093,17.8578413 19.9865669,17.703871 19.9865669,17.5310822 C19.9865669,17.3859509 20.0390083,17.2536506 20.1246988,17.153855 L23.4190508,14.1291948 C23.5163648,14.0165684 23.6569296,13.945571 23.8131728,13.945571 C23.9602252,13.945571 24.0929508,14.0082997 24.1894539,14.1092357 L33.861933,22.9913237 C33.9892522,23.0939706 34.0714286,23.2559245 34.0714286,23.4381226 C34.0714286,23.748059 33.8332794,23.9998289 33.5394449,23.9998289 L26.9504707,23.9998289 C26.8053105,23.9998289 26.6733958,23.9382408 26.5774333,23.8384453 Z M26.5774333,0.161098511 C26.6733958,0.0615881034 26.8053105,0 26.9504707,0 L33.5394449,0 C33.8332794,0 34.0714286,0.251769886 34.0714286,0.561706314 C34.0714286,0.743904453 33.9892522,0.905573224 33.861933,1.00822006 L24.1894539,9.89030807 C24.0929508,9.99152926 23.9602252,10.0542579 23.8131728,10.0542579 C23.6569296,10.0542579 23.5163648,9.98354562 23.4190508,9.87063409 L20.1246988,6.8459739 C20.0390083,6.74617837 19.9865669,6.613878 19.9865669,6.46874677 C19.9865669,6.29624305 20.060093,6.14198767 20.1765996,6.03848544 L26.5774333,0.161098511 Z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
</svg>
```

(These are 2 different images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to load the first one into a vector editor (eg Inkscape) and use the editor's drawing tools to manually recreate the shape(s).

Answer (score 0):

After 2-3 hours of messing with every possible online program. I downloaded Inkscape and tried to make a svg. 
It took another 2 hours because it was showing 0 path every time I was trying to make a svg. Then I found out it didn't detect the shape because it was white.

So I had to go back to photoshop, change the colour to black, save as a PNG then open it on Inkscape then re-path it. Took me way to long to figure this out.

You will need a thirdparty program to make svgs, there is no escaping them. I tried.

Thank you Paul for the suggestion.